# Upload document with metadata / Update document itself - Sharepoint 2010 Rest API

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, metadata

I need to upload documents on a Sharepoint Foundation 2010 in a Java EE project (Spring MVC). I'm using HttpClient to interact with the Sharepoint 2010 rest API, everything is working well but I have 2 questions :

- How can I upload a document with metadata ? For the moment, I upload the document and I update metadata just after the upload's complete. Because of that method my document is automatically in version 2.0, it's not the optimal behavior...
- How can I update the document ? I know how to update metadata but I have no ideas to update the document itself.

My upload :

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(this.username, this.password, "", "");
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    String url = "[url to library api - ..../ListData.svc/library]";
    String slug = "[url to document]";

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.getParams().setBooleanParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8; odata=verbose");
    post.setHeader("Slug", slug);

    MultipartEntity multipartContent = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    multipartContent.addPart(file.getName(), new FileBody(file));
    post.setEntity(multipartContent);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

My metadata's update :

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(this.username, this.password, "", "");
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);

    String url = "[url to document API - ....ListData.svc/library(ID)]";

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8; odata=verbose");
    post.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method", "MERGE");
    post.setHeader("If-Match", etag);

    post.setEntity(new StringEntity("[JSON update metadata]", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Comment: Hi Greg, can you share some details I have very similar requirement a stand alone program to interact with share point for uploading files. What ver. of Java you used any other external libraries you needed for this... thx